# Make my internal employees app updated all the time automatically

Tags: android, android-for-work

Im having issues getting my users to install updates of my app.

I need to say that my users are internal company employees, our app is for us internally and we need them to have the latest app always.

1. Is there a way to launch Android InAppUpdates (https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates) from the background so I show them all the time "UPDATE ME".
2. Is there a way through G-Suite admin to force this? I can force them to have it installed, but not to be updated all the time.